# I am a beginner and my AJAX code doesn't work

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, post

The client.html is opened at: https://localhost:3000/src/taskpane/taskpane.html.
The server.js is running by "node server.js", listening on port 4000.

When I click the button to send an ajax post to port 4000, I expected to get the response but it seems the request failed. F12 shows the following:

```
     Name       Status     Type      Initiator
taskpane.html    200     document     Other
jquery.min.js    200     script     taskpane.html
localhost      (failed)    xhr      jquery.min.js:4
```

The code is below:

taskpane.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="bid">123123</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('#bid').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'https://localhost:4000',
                data:{email: "example@example.com"},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function (data) {},  
            })
        })
        </script>     
    </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == "/") {
        res.end("hello world");
    }
}).listen(4000, function () {
    console.log("http://localhost:4000");
});
```

Comment: http vs https, have a look at your ajax url

Comment: Note that making an AJAX request across ports will count as a cross domain request. Ensure you're including CORS headers in the response.

Comment: Thanks. I installed "Web Server for Chrome" and now I am using http://localhost:8887. I changed the url in my post request to url:'http://localhost:8887' and server.js to listen on 8887. Now everything is in the same domain. But when I started server.js, open http://localhost:8887, click the button, I got POST http://localhost:8887/ 404 (Not Found). What am I missing?